# Merge two rows in one in SQL and delete the other row

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 rows in a table

```
empid  date            starttime   finishtime  total Work Hours
123    27/07/2016       21:00        3:30        6
123    28/07/2016       3:30         8:00        4
```

This query returns the data based on a date parameter of a stored procedure, what I want is when I run the stored proc for 27/07/2016 I should get

```
empid  date            starttime   finishtime  total Work Hours
123    27/07/2016       21:00        8:00        10
```

and when I run it for 28/07/2016 I should get nothing

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty basic thing going on here. I have to ask though, why do your "dates" look like strings? And which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server

Comment: Not sure what logic you are looking for. Can you explain the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to Kannan Kandasamy (I guess his answer was removed off the thread because I don't see it anymore), only I think it is important to also group by the date.
I do wish the OP was more specific, I can only speculate that the OP was looking for a way to accumulate hours on like a third shift worker - one who works starting at 21:00 and ends at 8:00 am the next day.  Now, to truly solve this issue the table should have timestamps instead of a date and a time because it this table logs an anomaly where the finish time comes before the starttime on the same date, but only half the time.
At the risk of being down voted here is my query to solve my highly speculative idea of what the problem is:

```
SELECT
    empid, 
    IF(starttime >= finishtime, `date`, DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) AS `date`,
    MAX(IF(starttime >= finishtime, starttime, NULL)) AS starttime,
    MAX(IF(finishtime >= starttime, finishtime,NULL)) AS finishtime,
    SUM(hours) AS hours
FROM 
    joe_table
WHERE 
    starttime IS NOT NULL
OR
    finishtime IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY empid, 2;
```